# Slice that represents concatenated slices

Tags: python, numpy, slice

The indices of a slice `slice(start, stop[, step])` can be often represented by `range(start, stop, step)` (or `range(*slice(start, stop, step).indices(length))` when taking the underlying dimensions into account).

Let's say I have even two, multidimensional slices and the second slice could be used as a slice into the result of applying the first slice.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(*(100, 100, 100))
a = data[::2, 7, :] # slice 1, a.shape = (50,100)
b = a[1, ::-1] # slice 2, b.shape = (100,)
```

I would like to find a general expression for calculating the single slice that does the same job. I know the dimensions of the underlying data structure.

```
c = data[2, 7, ::-1] # same as b
np.array_equal(b, c) # True
```

So, in getting from `[::2, 7, :]` and `[1, ::-1]` to `[2, 7, ::-1]`  in this example I would need a function like:

```
def concatenate_slices(shape, outer_slice, inner_slice):
    ...
    return combined_slice
```

where `outer_slice` and `inner_slice` would both be a tuple of slices. In the example `shape=(100, 100, 100)` and `outer_slice=(slice(None, None, 2), 7, slice(None, None, None))` and `inner_slice=(1, slice(None, None, -1))`.

I'm not sure how to do that efficiently.

My objects do something when `__getitem__(slice)` is called (no intermediate views) and I want to do that only once but still have the possibility to have slices of slices.

As an extension (optional) I would like to know what happens if I have ellipses in the slices. How can I then make the combination?

Comment: just for reference: `range(start, stop, step)` doesn't always produce the correct indices as it may also produce indices out of range, to create a valid range [`slice.indices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=slice.indices#slice.indices) needs to be used:`range(*slice(start, stop, step).indices(length))`. I'm not sure if it is possible to combine slices without taking the shape of the underlying structure into account.

Comment: @mata Thanks. You're right. Also in my case I would know the shape of the underlying structure. I edited a bit.

Comment: I guess it could be done with manually putting together a new slice by looking at the limits of the first two. I started writing it up but it's way too messy for my taste, there should be a better way (so I gave up).

Comment: I think you do need to know the dimensionality of the data.  Say vec=np.arange(10).  vec[::6] will be [0, 6].    vec[::6][::-1] will be [6, 0].  The equivalent slice would have been vec[6:-1:-6].  Now suppose vec=np.arange(13).  Now vec[::6][::-1] gives you [12,  6,  0].  So without knowing the array size you don't know where to start counting down from when you reverse the slice.

Comment: @Peter Right. The shape must be known and used. I added to the question, that I know it.

Comment: I'd suggest studying `np.lib.index_tricks`.  `np.r_` concatenates multiple slices by expanding them into their ranges, producing a list of indexes.  `np.ix_` (and `ogrid`) reshape indexes so they can be broadcast.  This dosen't do your task, but may give ideas on how implement your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the simple case: 1-d arrays. We'll need to keep track of the `start`, `stop`, and `step` values for the final slice, which we can update like so:

```
def update_1d(a, b, length):
  a_start, a_stop, a_step = a.indices(length)
  a_length = len(xrange(a_start, a_stop, a_step))
  if a_length == 0:
    # doesn't matter what b is if data[a] is []
    return a
  b_start, b_stop, b_step = b.indices(a_length)
  b_length = len(xrange(b_start, b_stop, b_step))
  if b_length == 0:
    # result will be empty, so we can exit early
    return slice(0, 0, 1)
  # convert b's start into a's coordinates, without wrapping around
  start = max(0, a_start + b_start * a_step)
  # steps are multiplicative, which makes things easy
  step = a_step * b_step
  # the stop index is the hard part because it depends on the sign of both steps
  x = a_start + b_stop * a_step
  if step < 0:
    # indexing backwards, so truncate if b's converted step goes below zero
    stop = x if x >= 0 else None
  elif a_step > 0:
    # both steps are positive, so take the smallest stop index
    stop = min(a_stop, x)
  else:
    # both steps are negative, so take the largest stop index
    stop = max(a_stop, x)
  return slice(start, stop, step)
```

Note that this expects `a` and `b` to be slices. You can usually convert other forms into slice objects, though. This even includes `Ellipsis` objects, assuming you know how many dimensions you have.

To extend this to the multidimensional case, we'll need to do some bookkeeping to keep track of which original dimension is getting sliced. For example, if you have `data[::2, 7, :][:, 2:-2]`, you'll have to map the second dimension of the second slice to the third dimension of the first slice.

Comment: Check this case: `a = slice(-1, 1, -2)`, `b = slice(0, -1, 1)`, `length=16`.

Comment: Thanks. That is already a good start. len(xrange()) should be inefficient Could one use floor((stop - start) / step) instead?

Comment: `len(xrange(...))` is actually quite fast, because the `xrange` object does essentially the same thing you suggested, but in C code. Also, Warren is right, the code I posted doesn't work for all cases. Stay tuned for a better version soon.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser this new version should have all the edge cases covered.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just have to go through the tedium of a analyzing each dimension, to build up either a new slice or an array of indices.  I doubt if there's a short cut.

To illustrate take your example:

```
In [77]: shape=(100,100,100)
In [78]: outer_slice=(slice(None, None, 2), 7, slice(None, None, None))
In [79]: inner_slice=(1, slice(None, None, -1))
```

The target is (right?):

```
(2, 7, slice(None,None,-1))
```

First dimension - make an array of the whole range of indices, and slice them sequentially:

```
In [80]: idx=np.arange(shape[0])
In [81]: idx[outer_slice[0]][inner_slice[0]]
Out[81]: 2
```

Could I deduce that from [::2] and [1]?  I have to reason that it starts at 0, the shape is large enough to yield a 2nd value, etc

Now for the 2nd dimension.  That's a scalar, so there's no corresponding `inner` slice.

```
In [82]: outer_slice[1]
Out[82]: 7
```

For the third, let's do that same as with the 1st, but taking into account the offset between outer and inner lists:

```
In [83]: idx=np.arange(shape[2])
In [84]: idx[outer_slice[2]][inner_slice[1]]
Out[84]: 
array([99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91,  ....7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])
```

Or I could deduce that `outer_slice[2]` does nothing, so I can use `inner_slice[1]` directly.

Of course it would be just as easy and efficient to apply the two slice tuples to the actual array.

```
X[outer_slice][inner_slice]
```

As long as `outer_slice` produces a view, combining them into a composite slice is not much of an improvement.

With shape and the slice tuples there's enough information to build a new tuple.  But it appears that the required logic will be quite involved, and require an in depth knowledge of slicing, and lots of testing.